# Cancel a subscription API - REST IONIC

Tags: angular, rest, http, ionic-framework, primeng

When i call a webservice, by autocomplete. For example i will Write the word "VEHICLE", when i start typing it will send a service to get all OBJECTS that start/have "VE" in the name. Those will take much more time than call "VEHICLE", so when i end typing the word it shows me the VEHICLE but after that shows me all the Objects that start with "VE", because it was still loading it. I want to know how i cancel previous call.

```
filterEntidadesRequisitantes(event) {
    this.api.getEntidadeRequisitante(event.query).subscribe(data => {
        this.entidadesRequisitantes = new Array<EntidadeList>();
        this.entidadesRequisitantes = data.entidadeList;
    },
    error => {
        console.log("error: " + error);
    });
};
```

This is the method where i call the service.

**UPDATE** **
 I'm making confusion with other filter i have. Where instead of pass data to an array i pass it to a JSON, { }, and i don't clean it every time the method is called. Sorry for wasted time. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I am not sure about primeng autocomplete. Would that be okay if i share a custom autocomplete code in simple steps using rxjs?

Comment: @KarthickManoharan Feel free to share it! The more options we have the better!

Comment: I found a article which describes it better https://blog.strongbrew.io/building-a-safe-autocomplete-operator-with-rxjs/

Answer (score 1):

- Declare property subscription:

  ```
    public subscription:any;
  ```
- Modify your code like that:

  ```
    filterEntidadesRequisitantes(event){
     this.entidadesRequisitantes = new Array<EntidadeList>();

     this.subscription = this.api.getEntidadeRequisitante(event.query).subscribe(data=>{
      this.entidadesRequisitantes = data.entidadeList;
     },
     error=>{
      console.log("error: " + error)
     });
  };
  ```
- Finally implement NgDestroy:

  ```
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Just make your array empty before sending the request.

```
filterEntidadesRequisitantes(event){


 this.entidadesRequisitantes = new Array<EntidadeList>();

 this.api.getEntidadeRequisitante(event.query).subscribe(data=>{
  this.entidadesRequisitantes = data.entidadeList;
 },
 error=>{
  console.log("error: " + error)
 });
};
```

Comment: It doesn't even load if i make array empty out of calling api service. Using Autocomplete component from primeng.